# CDI dependency injection not working in JAX-RS resource

Tags: jax-rs, cdi

I'm building a REST API using JAX-RS framework for a school project but for some reason the CDI doesn't work, when I manually create a new instance of a class everything works as it should but when I rely on dependency injection I get a error that the instance of the class does not exists. I use all the right annotations, have all the plugins installed, maven dependency's are all good but for some reason dependency injection just doesn't work. I'm using Jakarta EE 9.1.0. and work in Intellij IDE ultimate edition.

```
@Path("/login")
public class LoginResource {

    @Inject
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    private UserNotAvailableException userNotAvailableException;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response login(LoginRequestDTO loginRequestDTO) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("test");
        if(loginRequestDTO == null){
            return Response.status(200).entity(userNotAvailableException).build();
        } else {
            if (userDAO.getUser(loginRequestDTO.getUser(), loginRequestDTO.getPassword())) {
                System.out.println("test");

                var username = loginRequestDTO.getUser();

                var token = TokenGenerator.generateNewToken();
                var loginResponseDTO = new LoginResponseDTO(username, token);
                userDAO.insertToken(loginRequestDTO.getUser(), token);

                var response = Response.ok(loginResponseDTO).build();
                System.out.println("test");

                return response;
            } else {
                return Response.ok(401).build();
            }
        }
    }

}


@ApplicationScoped
public class UserDAO {
    @Inject
    DatabaseConnection databaseConnection;
    @Inject
    private DatabaseProperties databaseProperties;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    public boolean getUser(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("test");
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseConnection.getJdbcUrl(), databaseConnection.getDbUsername(), databaseConnection.getDbPassword())) {
            System.out.println("test");

            String sql = "SELECT username, password FROM Users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
            PreparedStatement stm = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            stm.setString(1, username);
            stm.setString(2, password);
            System.out.println("test");

            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("test");

            if (rs.next()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error communicating with database " + databaseProperties.connectionString(), e);
        }
        return false;
    }


@ApplicationScoped
public class DatabaseConnection {

    public String getJdbcUrl() {
        return "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=Spotitube";
    }

    public String getDbUsername() {
        return "spotitube";
    }

    public String getDbPassword() {

        return "12345";
    }
    
}
```

I tried different annotations, checking all the plugins, cleaning and resetting maven, I know the problem is injection but I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: check the `bean-discovery-mode` value in the `beans.xml` file

Comment: bean-discovery-mode is set to 'all' and the beans.xml file is under resources(root)/META-INF/beans.xml

Comment: It would be useful to add (1) the pom.xml and (2) what kind of server are you using.